# Is there a way I can create a class or anonymous object to be used in a Generic <> inside a method?

Tags: c#, generics

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
public partial class ABC
{
    public int Abc { get; set; }
    public int Def { get; set; }
}

public myFunc(int adminTestId)
{
    var sql = @"xxxxx";
    var x = await db.Database.SqlQuery<ABC>(sql).ToListAsync();
    return x; // this will return an array of ABC's to my web client
              // x is never used internally in my code.
}
```

The class `ABC` is used only in this one place and the rest of my code has no need to know about it. 
Is there any way that I can move this definition of the class inside the method or pass an anonymous class to the generic `< >` of the .SqlQuery function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use type inference, by passing an instance of the class as a parameter.  This will let the compiler infer the generic parameter from the value:

```
Query<T> SqlQuery<T>(string query, T sample) {
    // Ignore the sample parameter
}

SqlQuery("...", new { Abc = 0, Def = 0 })
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more. I really want to move that definition inside the method or make it anonymouns if possible.

Comment: Would your suggestion require me to change SqlQuery? That is not a function of mine and I have no access to change it.

Comment: @SamanthaJ: Then you can write a wrapper extension method that simply calls the original method.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way that I can move this definition inside the method?

No. You can move the class `ABC` to inside the class containing the method, but not into the method.

> or pass an anonymous type as a type argument?

Yes, the technique you want to use is called "cast by example"; a web search for that will give you examples, or see SLaks' answer.

Comment: If you don't mind. Can you give me an example using my code so I can see what you mean. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension method:

```
public static T CastByExample<T>(this object o, T example) 
{ 
    return (T) o; 
}
```

Then:

```
var sql = @"xxxxx";
var x = await db.Database.SqlQuery<ABC>(sql).ToListAsync();
var abc = x.CastByExample(new {Abc=0,Def=0});
```

Now you can use: abc.Abc && abc.Def 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2007/11/22/t-castbyexample-t-object-o-t-example.aspx

Comment: I am sorry but I do not see where you define the class ABC in your answer. Also note that I don't want to use abc.Abc etc. I need this in only one place and that is where I pass it to the SqlQuery.